# CSS not updating in Chapter 10 of Michael Hartl's Rail's tutorial

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In chapter 10 of the tutorial I'm changing the CSS for microposts to look different. However they won't update on my local server. I tried restarting the server and resetting and repopulating the database but still no luck. Why is this happening?

**Custom CSS File**

```
/* microposts */

.microposts {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;

  li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  }
}
.content {
  display: block;
}
.timestamp {
  color: $grayLight;
}
.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
aside {
  textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: And this file is `custom.css.scss`?

Comment: It is probably not included.

Comment: Try to reset the cache memory in your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my computer somehow solved the problem. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: Don't make this kind of 'jokes' in stackoverflow with a permanent nickname or you'll get tones of dislikes :)

Comment: @scaryguy what do you mean?